# How much harder is it for an American mathematician to teach in France rather than in the U.S.?

Tags: mathematics, professorship, france

How difficult is it for a U.S. educated (PhD level) mathematician to land a tenured mathematics research/professorship in France, relative to achieving the same position in the U.S.?

Comment: The difficulty can vary enormously depending on the circumstances.  If you speak fluent French and have spent time visiting French institutions, then your chances will generally be much better than if neither of these is the case.  If you know French mathematicians, it's worth talking with them about the details of your case.  (If you don't know any French mathematicians, then that's a bad sign.)

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect ff524's comment, I'm asking for the difficulty of achieving a position in France relative to the difficulty of achieving a comparable position in the U.S.

Comment: @Danny Seeing as "U.S. educated" implies you are fluent in English, but not necessarily fluent in French (as spoken in France--Canadians, etc. speak a rather different dialect), the difficulty ranges from "impossible, go master French" to "possible".

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Canadian French is close enough to French French that someone "only fluent in Canadian French" would have no trouble at all in France... Maybe a few slang words here and there and the accent would differ, but that's it.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That's an opinion that must vary widely.  I have a colleague who is a professor in France, and of a visit to French speaking Canada basically said it was a jarring experience, and what they spoke sounded nothing like "real" French.  He did manage, and still goes there for conferences regularly.  So, yes, you can achieve an understanding, *with suitable effort*, but it's not simply slang words but also pronunciation and even how one structures their thoughts in(to) the language (which is culturally influenced).